# How to create new column using SUMX and from that column calculate average in power bi

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi, dax, data-analysis

what i have tried is

```
order value = 
sumx(
     Table1, 
    (Table1[Total]+Table1[WET]+Table1[Admin Fee Dollars])
    -Table1[GST]
)
```

but what i want is average of order value
how can this be achieved?

[![sample table][1]][1]

Comment: Your requirements are a bit unclear. where is column "order value"? and what do you mean by average? from the entire table? or for some selected rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this measure:

```
Average Of order Value =
VAR Summary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Table1,
        "order value",
            CALCULATE ( SUMX ( Table1, [Total] + [WET] + [Admin Fee Dollars] - [GST] ) )
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX ( Summary, [ordervalue] )
```